# Jupyter Notebook in VS Code stuck on loading

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, langchain, py-langchain

I am making a project on LangChain which utilises the method load() of class UnstructuredURLLoader however my Jupyter notebook is stuck on loading as shown in the image[image]

I had earlier thought it is an issue related to the internal function of LangChain however it has more to do with me not being to fetch the url I tried fetching it using the requests.get(url) and it worked fine.
But while using the load() it showed
**Error fetching or processing https://www.url.com, exception: b"cannot read magic file `/usr/share/misc/magic' (Bad address)"**

Comment: are you using Linux machine? please share your code as well